# allow java applets in browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, java-applet

I really don't get the policy of not allowing java applets in browser. I mean, I understand that the java does not run automatically for security reasons, but it seems that there is actually no way **how to allow to run applets manually** either ( which I know that are not malware ).

**Is there a way to do that ?**

- in Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome ?
- under Linux ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 if it does matter ?

  e.g for this sites:
- http://watchmaker.uncommons.org/examples/biomorphs.php
- http://www.falstad.com/mathphysics.html
- http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/73427

... I'm fighting this problem all the time last few years ... I'm almost never able to run any applet even If I set security setting as low as possible, update java plug-in accept all certificates and other obfucations ....

this obsession with security which kills functionality is really ill. Why the hell such **educational things** as this physics applets should suffer, because few commercial companies fear that they will be hacked.

Comment: I have never and still don't have problems running Java applets in a browser.  Chrome and Firefox might block the content by default, but you can unblock the content, I use Java applets in those browsers daily.

Comment: According to https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033 Chrome version 42 and higher doesn't support NPAPI-based plugins, which is needed for Java, Silverlight, and Unity.